# Blur function for cs50 PSET4, where are the errors?

Tags: c, filter, blur, cs50

I have been stuck with this function for days now. I looked at other people questions, I watched youtube tutorials videos, but I can't get it right.
The task is part of Harvard's CS50 course (https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/less/).
Any kind of help would be much appreciated! I really don't want to go on with the course without understanding what the problem is.

```
//check if pixels are valid
bool valid_pixel(int r, int c, int height, int width)
{
    return r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < height && c < width;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //create a copy of the original image
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    int red, green, blue, count;
    red = green = blue = count = 0;
    //iterate through rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        //iterate through columns
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            //move one pixel up to one pixel down in the rows
            for (int r = i - 1; r <= i + 1; r++)
            {
                //move one pixel left to one pixel right in the columns
                for (int c = j - 1; c <= j + 1; c++)
                {
                    //check if they are unvalid pixels
                    if (valid_pixel(r, c, height, width))
                    {
                        //count every valid pixel
                        count ++;
                        //"store" every pixel color
                        red += image[r][c].rgbtRed;
                        green += image[r][c].rgbtGreen;
                        blue += image[r][c].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
            //calculate average values
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round((float)red / count);
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((float)green / count);
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((float)blue / count);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
```

Comment: Please move `red = green = blue = count = 0;` down about 6 lines, to be in the proper loop.

Comment: Also, the first set of two nested loops which copy `image[][]` to `temp[][]` can be removed, since `temp[][]` is where you are writing the blurred pixel values. You copy them back to `image[][]` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is that you forget to reset `red`, `blue` and `green` variables (that you sum up) after each outer loop iteration. You should put this line inside the main loop-

```c
red = green = blue = count = 0;
```

Also, you're copying the image into another temporary image and copying that temporary image into the original image again in the end. This is very in-efficient. You should not copy the pixels from the original image into the blurred image at first. You can put the modified values directly into this temporary image. And in the end, use [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) to efficiently move entire rows to the original image at once. (Remember to `#include <string.h>`)

```c
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    
    RGBTRIPLE blurred_img[height][width];
    //iterate through rows
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        //iterate through columns
        for (int j = 0, red, green, blue, count; j < width; j++)
        {
            // Reset the variables
            red = blue = green = count = 0;
            //move one pixel up to one pixel down in the rows
            for (int r = i - 1; r <= i + 1; r++)
            {
                //move one pixel left to one pixel right in the columns
                for (int c = j - 1; c <= j + 1; c++)
                {
                    //check if they are unvalid pixels
                    if (valid_pixel(r, c, height, width))
                    {
                        //count every valid pixel
                        count++;
                        //"store" every pixel color
                        red += image[r][c].rgbtRed;
                        green += image[r][c].rgbtGreen;
                        blue += image[r][c].rgbtBlue;
                    }
                }
            }
            //calculate average values
            blurred_img[i][j].rgbtRed = round((float)red / count);
            blurred_img[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((float)green / count);
            blurred_img[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((float)blue / count);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Copy the new image over to the original, row by row
        memmove(image[i], blurred_img[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * width);
    }
    return;
}
```

This is assuming `valid_pixel` is correct. To determine whether the pixel position is valid you can just do-

```c
if (k > 0 && k < height && l > -1 && l < width))
```

Notice however, when `r` (the row) is invalid, the innermost loop (column loop) is still iterated until `c == width` even though the entirety of this loop is useless, because `r` is invalid and it'll stay that way until the innermost loop completes and `r` increments.

For efficiency, you should `break` whenever `r` is invalid-

```c
if (r < 0 || r > height - 1)
{
    break;
}
if (c > -1 && c < width)
{
    //count every valid pixel
    count++;
    //"store" every pixel color
    red += image[r][c].rgbtRed;
    green += image[r][c].rgbtGreen;
    blue += image[r][c].rgbtBlue;
}
```